# OWS_SiteName Crawled Property in SharePoint refiners does not return all results

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results

The crawled property `OWS_SiteName` is mapped to one of the ManagedProperty called `RefinerString00`. We have a result page for 'Pages'. And have added the '`RefinerString00`' as the refiners.

We want to filter the pages based on the sites from where the pages exists. However not all sites are listed in the refiner, Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you viewing it with an account that has access to everything? Search results are security trimmed so if you don't have access, it won't show up. Has the site been crawled since making the mapping change?

Comment: yes i have site collection admin acesss

Comment: Did you ever solve this?